# I don't understand "the nearest" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammar, word-meaning

This is the first scene of the documentary, where thousands of penguins are facing into snow storm.

> Narrator : Imagine our world without sun.
>
> Male Emperor Penguins are facing **the nearest** that exists on planet Earth - winter in Antarctica.
>
> *BBC Planet Earth*

I feel like there has to be something after "the nearest", like "the nearest *winter* that exists on earth . . .", Is it allowed to omit some words like this in English?

And second, I don't exactly understand the meaning of "the nearest" here.
Does it mean "these penguins are the *first* ones to face the winter"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I heard, Winter in Antarctica is dark as night. So I read that phrase as meaning

> the nearest thing to our world without sun